# Taxonomy page view template override

Tags: 8, views

I have a view showing content and a view showing taxonomy terms.

For the first one, one of the suggested template files is *views-view--{viewname}.html.twig*. I don't get the same template file suggested for the second view.

Am I missing something, or is it just the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the template suggestions for views are sometimes not complete. As [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.9.x) says, though, the *views-view--[view_name].html.twig* template file, where *[view_name]* is the view machine name, can be used for every view, independently from what the view shows.

> All views templates can be overridden with a variety of names, using the view, the display ID of the view, the display type of the view, or some combination thereof.
>
> For each view, there will be a minimum of two templates used. The first is used for all views: [views-view.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.9.x/search/views-view.html.twig).
>
> The second template is determined by the style selected for the view. Note that certain aspects of the view can also change which style is used; for example, arguments which provide a summary view might change the style to one of the special summary styles.
>
> The default style for all views is [views-view-unformatted.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.9.x/search/views-view-unformatted.html.twig).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable twig debug - this will output, as html comments (you'll have to inspect the dom), all twig override options above all twig rendered output. Check out this page for more info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

One note I'll make is that I would use the development.services.yml file to make this override if you're using a settings.local.php. You can find that file and information about how to use it at sites/development.services.yml. You'll have to copy that file to your site's directory for your current site, e.g. sites/default/development.services.yml and then add the configuration for enabling twig debug there.